# Determine if security software is blocking application process on RHEL Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, java, rhel7, jmx

We deployed a networking application implemented in Java 8 on RHEL 7.1. Periodically, the application gets stuck attempting to communicate on non-standard ports. Is there any way to determine if other processes, such as anti-virus, etc., is blocking or interfering with our application?

Comment: have you installed antivirus on Redhat? the only time that I seen antivirus on Linux was on mailserver for mail virus scanning.

Comment: Did you check the selinux audit log? Did you make a list of which processes listen on which ports?

Comment: using Qualsys only; this turned out to be a separate issue not related to security or scanning software, but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The place to look would be the logs. On recent versions of EL that would be in `/var/log`. If SELinux is enabled (see getenforce(1) ) I would take a long hard look at /var/log/audit/audit.log (and any previous versions you find there).

In particular look for AVC `denied` messages these should let you know if SELinux is playing a part in you troubles.

Solving the problem depends upon what you find.

Comment: This is great for future reference!